# How to put repeating number on range operator perl

Tags: perl

Hi guy's i hv a question about range operator in perl

my simple scripts

```
@nums = (111..444);print "@nums\n";
```

how do i make the output like

```
111 222 333 444
```

Comment: Do you have to use the range operator? What if you just range from 1 to 4 and print the number 3 times instead?

Comment: yeah,i have to use that sir.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not need the other numbers in between at all, but want to have an array that has the repeating ones as described, the easy and elegant way could be:

```
@nums = map {$_ x3} 1..4;
```

have fun

Comment: @vanHoesel haven't seen you around here o/

Answer (score 3):

Two alternative solutions. One, perhaps, more readable than [vanHoesel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40338261/7231):

```
@nums = map { $_ * 111 } 1 .. 4;
```

And another which is really inefficient and ridiculous:

```
@nums = grep { ! ($_ % 111) } 111 .. 444;
```

Please don't use the second one :-)

Comment: hi,thanks sir..but actually my script is like this @nums = (map { $_ * 111 } 1 .. 4,map { $_ * 1111 } 1 .. 4); ,but when i print it the second element not sequencing,how's that?

Comment: That seems to be a precedence issue. Try `@nums = (map { $_ * 111 } 1 .. 4),(map { $_ * 1111 } 1 .. 4)`.